# Any Group G of order 2, $\mathrm{Aut} (G) \cong \langle e \rangle$

Tags: group-theory, automorphism-group

Suppose that $\lvert G \rvert = 2$. Then I want to show that $\mathrm{Aut} (G) = \langle e \rangle$. I know that $G \cong \mathbb{Z}_2 \cong S_2 \cong D_2$ (by Cauchy's Theorem all of which are cyclic and abelian).

Let $\beta: G \to G$ be an automorphism. Then I know that $G$ is cyclic (let's say that $G$ is generated by $a$, i.e., $\langle a \rangle = \{a : a^2 = e\} = \{e, a\}= G$).

Is it true that $\beta$ must be the $\mathrm{id}$ map? And do I just need to prove that $\lvert \mathrm{Aut}(G) \rvert$ = 1?

Comment: *Hint :* An automorphism must send $e$ to $e$, and must be bijective...

Comment: Well, there are just four functions $G \to G$: the identity map, the constant functions $e$ and $a$, and a transposition that exchanges these two. The only maps that are homomorphisms are the identity and the constant function $e$, but the latter is not bijective.

Comment: Note that an automorphism is an isomorphism. But if $f:G\to G$ then $f(e)=e$. This means that $f$ is an isomorphis if and only if $f(a) = a$.